# Get currentUser inside a Lift RestHelper

Tags: http, authentication, scala, lift

Could anyone please help me to retreive the authenticated user who initiated a REST call? I'm using Lift with the RestHelper

In my `Boot.scala` I have the following:

```
LiftRules.httpAuthProtectedResource.prepend {
  case Req(List("api", "incomingCall", incomingCall), _, GetRequest) => Full(AuthRole("admin"))
}

LiftRules.authentication = HttpBasicAuthentication("lift") {
  case (username, password, req) => {
    User.find(By(User.firstName, username)) match {
      case Full(user) if user.password.match_?(password) => {
        userRoles(AuthRole("admin"))
        User.logUserIn(user) //I tried with and without this line
         true
      }
      case x => {
        false
      }
    }
  }
}

LiftRules.dispatch.append(IncomingCallRest)
```

And my IncomingCallRest.scala file looks like this:

```
object IncomingCallRest extends RestHelper {
  serve {
    case "api" :: "incomingCall" :: incomingCall :: _ JsonGet _ => {
      val currentUser = User.currentUser openOr User; //<--- On this line I'm trying to access the User, but it returns a blank user
      val messageWithUser = (incomingCall, currentUser.userIdAsString)
      ChatServer ! messageWithUser
      JString(incomingCall)
    }
  }
}
```

`User.currentUser` does not return the authenticated user.

As you might see my code is based on the [ChatServer example](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-2.3.html). I'm making the same call to `User.currentUser` from ChatIn.scala and there it works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creator of Lift suggested the following in an [old thread](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/0f83646934c03b07):

> Sessions are not initialized this early in the HTTP request/response 
>   cycle.  However, RequestVars are.  My suggestion is to put User into a 
>   RequestVar and then in your API module, read the RequestVar and put it into 
>   a SessionVar.

I changed my code as follows to implement his suggestions:

```
//IncomingCallRest.scala
object userIdRequestVar extends RequestVar[String]("Default") //This RequestVar is set in Boot.scala
object IncomingCallRest extends RestHelper {
  serve {
    case "api" :: "incomingCall" :: incomingCall :: _ JsonGet _ => {
      val messageWithUser = (incomingCall, userIdRequestVar.is)
      ChatServer ! messageWithUser
      JString(incomingCall)
    }
  }
}

//Boot.scala
LiftRules.authentication = HttpBasicAuthentication("lift") {
  case (username, password, req) => {
    User.find(By(User.firstName, username)) match {
      case Full(user) if user.password.match_?(password) => {
        userRoles(AuthRole("admin"))
        userIdRequestVar.set(user.userIdAsString) //Set the RequestVar
        true
      }
      case x => {
        false
      }
    }
  }
}
```